# json response to dynamic class conversion

Tags: c#, json

i am having issue to get information from json response, i was trying to get information for label and value only from details object of json response, however i am unable to get those information because while converting json to c# classes from http://json2csharp.com/ gives different classes for 'General', 'AC Adapter' etc.. however in my case it will not work because the response having dynamic classes and therefore i cannot create classes.

```
 {
  "data": {
    "General": {
      "label": "General",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Operating System",
          "value": "Google Chrome OS"
        },
        {
          "label": "Product Type",
          "value": "Chromebook"
        }
      ]
    },
    "AC Adapter": {
      "label": "AC Adapter",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Input",
          "value": "AC 120/230 V ( 50/60 Hz )"
        },
        {
          "label": "Output",
          "value": "45 Watt , 20 V , 2.25 A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Audio & Video": {
      "label": "Audio & Video",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Camera",
          "value": "Yes - 720p"
        },
        {
          "label": "Graphics Processor",
          "value": "Intel HD Graphics"
        },
        {
          "label": "Resolution",
          "value": "1 Megapixel"
        },
        {
          "label": "Sound",
          "value": "Stereo speakers , microphone"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Battery": {
      "label": "Battery",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Capacity",
          "value": "45 Wh"
        },
        {
          "label": "Run Time",
          "value": "Up to 10 hours"
        },
        {
          "label": "Technology",
          "value": "3-cell lithium ion"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Communications": {
      "label": "Communications",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Features",
          "value": "Dual stream (2x2)"
        },
        {
          "label": "Wireless",
          "value": "Bluetooth 4.0, 802.11a/b/g/n/ac"
        },
        {
          "label": "Wireless Controller",
          "value": "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 - M.2 Card"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Connections & Expansion": {
      "label": "Connections & Expansion",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Interfaces",
          "value": "USB 3.0 � 2 x USB 2.0 � HDMI � Headphone/microphone combo jack"
        },
        {
          "label": "Memory Card Reader",
          "value": "Yes ( microSD )"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Dimensions & Weight": {
      "label": "Dimensions & Weight",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Dimensions (WxDxH)",
          "value": "11.8 in x 8.5 in x 0.9 in"
        },
        {
          "label": "Weight",
          "value": "2.84 lbs"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Display": {
      "label": "Display",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Features",
          "value": "Anti-glare"
        },
        {
          "label": "Image Aspect Ratio",
          "value": "16:9"
        },
        {
          "label": "LCD Backlight Technology",
          "value": "LED backlight"
        },
        {
          "label": "Resolution",
          "value": "1366 x 768 ( HD )"
        },
        {
          "label": "Type",
          "value": "11.6\""
        },
        {
          "label": "Widescreen",
          "value": "Yes"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Input": {
      "label": "Input",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Features",
          "value": "Spill-resistant"
        },
        {
          "label": "Type",
          "value": "Keyboard, touchpad"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Manufacturer Warranty": {
      "label": "Manufacturer Warranty",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Service & Support",
          "value": "Limited warranty - 1 year - carry-in"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Memory": {
      "label": "Memory",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Max RAM Supported",
          "value": "8 GB"
        },
        {
          "label": "RAM",
          "value": "4 GB ( provided memory is soldered )"
        },
        {
          "label": "Speed",
          "value": "1600 MHz"
        },
        {
          "label": "Technology",
          "value": "DDR3L SDRAM"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Miscellaneous": {
      "label": "Miscellaneous",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Features",
          "value": "Security lock slot (cable lock sold separately), administrator password, hard drive password, power-on password"
        },
        {
          "label": "Included Accessories",
          "value": "Power adapter"
        },
        {
          "label": "Localization",
          "value": "English"
        },
        {
          "label": "Manufacturer Selling Program",
          "value": "TopSeller"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Processor / Chipset": {
      "label": "Processor / Chipset",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "64-bit Computing",
          "value": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "label": "CPU",
          "value": "Intel Celeron N3050 / 1.6 GHz"
        },
        {
          "label": "Cache",
          "value": "2 MB"
        },
        {
          "label": "Features",
          "value": "Integrated memory controller"
        },
        {
          "label": "Max Turbo Speed",
          "value": "2.16 GHz"
        },
        {
          "label": "Number of Cores",
          "value": "Dual-Core"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Storage": {
      "label": "Storage",
      "details": [
        {
          "label": "Main Storage",
          "value": "16 GB SSD - ( eMMC )"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: can you provide some example like, thanks

Comment: If you already have classes created, it can convert the json to your objects, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json);`. But if you don't have classes, you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://json2csharp.com/ gives different classes for 'General', 'AC Adapter' etc

This works better: https://quicktype.io/?l=cs&r=json2csharp

However, I think your `data` is actually a dictionary here. So the final contract:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data : Dictionary<string, Item> { }

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public Detail[] Details { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And if you use Newtonsoft, deserialization:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks, i get the 14 object, but i need to loop through and fetch Details array 'label' and 'value' information.

response.Data["General"].Details[0].Label

but i don't want to use "General" a static value. thanks

Comment: `response.Data.Values.ToArray()`?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to convert a json string to C# dynamic object, look at [this SO question](http://if%20you%20just%20want%20to%20convert%20a%20json%20string%20to%20C#%20dynamiv%20object,%20look%20at%20the). The code is in the final version.